# Congratulations Worldbuilders - all systems green

Tags: discussion

I don't want anyone to start expecting any immediate graduation from beta (that can take years) but on Sunday [our Area51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding) hit Excellent in the final category.

[image: All System Green]

We've been on excellent everywhere else for a long time but our questions per day activity level (at least partially due to the Space Challenge but it was rising without that) has finally caught up with the rest.

Good job everyone, and keep building those worlds :)

Comment: I see you beat Monica to meta. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I shamelessly stole her screenshot too :D We are actually up to 10.6 on the questions per day stats at the time of writing this post, so still rising.

Comment: . . . and 1 more avid user, and 15 more total users. The theoretical weekend drop in activity doesn't seem to have hurt us this weekend.

Comment: The drop is real. Last week we averaged ~13 questions per day during the week and ~6 during the weekend. Some previous weeks we've averaged ~8 during the week and ~2 during the weekend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel like this deserves an answer.

/salute

Yes Sir...I guess.

Hooray us.  Have a baloon.

[image]

Comment: Whats that green stuff on the right side?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg no idea just grabbed the image from a quick google search...

Comment: @DavidGrinberg `Download From [indiscernable word].com`

Comment: Dreamstime.com maybe?  Searching Google images for "balloon with string" finds a bunch of images from there with a similar looking note on either the right side or the bottom.